# Input/output data with specific directory path name in Fortran

Tags: file-io, fortran

I am importing data from a directory `'/Users/rob/Desktop/DISSERTATION/DSMCDATA/'` into a Fortran code and exporting the same data with a different name into this same directory. The code is an .f90 file in a different directory `'/Users/rob/Desktop/DISSERTATION/DSMCCODE/'`. The code imports the data again to check if it was indeed exported into the correct directory. It is apparent that I am able to initially import the data from the specific directory without problems. However, I am unable to successfully export data into this specific directory.

```
program exporttest

implicit none

integer(8), parameter :: Stot= 2 
integer(8), dimension(:), allocatable :: Nfp, Nf, Nfvp, Nfv
integer(4) :: rank, s
character(10) :: rankstring, sstring
character(*), parameter :: datadir= '/Users/rob/Desktop/DISSERTATION/DSMCDATA/'
character(50) :: NfTfile

type Specietype 
    integer(8), dimension(:), allocatable :: NfT, NfvT
end type Specietype
type(Specietype), dimension(:), allocatable :: SpecieT

allocate(SpecieT(Stot))
allocate(Nfp(Stot), Nfvp(Stot))
allocate(SpecieT(Stot)%NfT(1), SpecieT(Stot)%NfvT(1))
rank= 0

! import data

do s= 1, Stot, 1
    write(sstring, '(I5)') s
    allocate(Nf(1))

    open (unit= 0, file= datadir // adjustl(adjustr(sstring) // ':' // 'Nfmat.bin'), & 
    status= 'old', form= 'unformatted', access= 'stream')
    read(0) Nfp(s)
    close(0)

    Nf(1)= Nfp(s)
    SpecieT(s)%NfT= Nf 

    deallocate(Nf)
end do
deallocate(Nfp)

write(*, *) 'NfT s1= ', SpecieT(1)%NfT(1)
write(*, *) 'NfT s2= ', SpecieT(2)%NfT(1)   

! export data

write(rankstring, '(i10)')  rank 

do s= 1, Stot, 1
    write(sstring, '(I5)') s

    NfTfile= & 
    datadir // adjustl(adjustr(rankstring) // ':' // & 
    adjustl(adjustr(sstring) // ':' // 'NfTfort.bin'))
    open(unit= 0, status= 'replace', file= NfTfile, form= 'unformatted', &
    access= 'stream')
    write(0) SpecieT(s)%NfT
    close(0)

end do

! import exported data

do s= 1, Stot, 1
    write(sstring, '(I5)') s
    allocate(Nfv(1))

    open (unit= 0, file= datadir // adjustl(adjustr(rankstring) // ':' // & 
    adjustl(adjustr(sstring) // ':' // 'NfTfort.bin')), & 
    status= 'old', form= 'unformatted', access= 'stream')
    read(0) Nfvp(s)
    close(0)

    Nfv(1)= Nfvp(s)
    SpecieT(s)%NfvT= Nfv

    deallocate(Nfv)
end do
deallocate(Nfvp)

write(*, *) 'NfvT s1= ', SpecieT(1)%NfvT(1)
write(*, *) 'NfvT s2= ', SpecieT(2)%NfvT(1)

end program exporttest
```

I am compiling the code as follows:
`mpif90 -O3 exporttest.f90 -o executablefile`
and receiving the following output:

```
NfT s1=                     1
NfT s2=                     1
At line 68 of file exporttest.f90
Fortran runtime error: Cannot open file '/Users/rob/Desktop/DISSERTATION/DSMCDATA/0:1:NfTfort.bin': No such file or directory

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x1052bee46
#1  0x1052bf718
#2  0x1052bfd7c
#3  0x10534005a
#4  0x1053406e3
#5  0x1050c59de
#6  0x1050c5c5e
```

It is apparent that the exported file `'/Users/rob/Desktop/DISSERTATION/DSMCDATA/0:1:NfTfort.bin'` is not being created in the directory `'/Users/rob/Desktop/DISSERTATION/DSMCDATA/'`. Any ideas why this is happening?

The problem lies in the final export section

```
open (unit= 0, file= datadir // adjustl(adjustr(rankstring) // ':' // & 
adjustl(adjustr(sstring) // ':' // 'NfTfort.bin')), & 
status= 'old', form= 'unformatted', access= 'stream')
read(0) Nfvp(s)
close(0)
```

Although the import section of the code demonstrates that the file declaration in the open statement is able to distinguish and correctly combine the directory path name string with the concatenation of running index strings, namely,

```
file= datadir // adjustl(adjustr(sstring) // ':' // 'Nfmat.bin')
```

The export section of the code here does not support that sort of string combination. The files are dumped into the preceding directory and are text edit files instead. I'm not sure why the string concatenation works correctly in the import section and not in the export section of the code.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions to get more attention. Fortran 90 is just one old and obsolete version and your code is NOT Fortran 90 compatible. It requires Fortran 2003. File suffix `.f90` does NOT mean Fortran 90, but any free form Fortran, even Fortran 2018.

Comment: Also, kind constants 4 and 8 in `integer(8)` are ugly and not portable. They do not always mean 4 bytes and 8 bytes.

Comment: i woudn't use a colon in a filename. It is not forbidden, but it is asking for trouble.

Comment: I have posted a solution that gets the job done with a minor caveat. I am not sure how to avoid the limitation, yet this works in it's own right. Any ideas of how to generalize this to any separate directory would be great.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way around this is to ensure that the export open statement recognizes where the file path ends and the rest of the file name string begins. Done piece-wise, the export section of the code becomes:

```
! export data

write(rankstring, '(i10)')  rank 

do s= 1, Stot, 1
    write(sstring, '(I5)') s

    expstring= adjustl(adjustr(rankstring) // '_' // adjustl(adjustr(sstring) & 
    // '_'))

    NfTfile= adjustl(adjustr(expstring) // adjustl(adjustr('NfTfort.bin')))
    open(unit= 0, file= adjustl(adjustr(datadir) // adjustl(adjustr(NfTfile))), & 
    status= 'replace', form= 'unformatted', access= 'stream')
    write(0) SpecieT(s)%NfT(1)
    close(0)

end do
```

where `character(10) :: expstring` is defined in the preamble. The only draw-back with this method when exporting data to a separate directory is that `datadir` must be a directory before the one containing the code. Otherwise, a text file is created in the code directory with a file name that begins with the ending of the path name (namely the path name after the code directory). In this case, the same problem persists- it cannot distinguish where the path name ends and the file name begins and the extension is not recognized. At any rate, data may be successfully exported and accessed from a separate directory prior to the code directory with the above method, minding this caveat.

Comment: Uh, only now I noticed you are opening the file on unit 0. That is a bad idea because most compilers preconnect standard error to unit 0.

Comment: I dont see any real difference from the code in the question except that the filename is simpler and does not contain `:`.

Comment: There isn't really a difference. I just split up the string with the path name separated from the file name and then put them together. It works but I'm not quite sure why the original way doesn't.

Comment: Well, the file name is different, isn't it? It did contain `:` before, didn't it?